# Microsoft Teams Auth Flow cross origin error

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams

I am getting the following error when I do an auth flow in Microsoft Teams. The getContext call never returns when called. Note this is a page opened in a popup when called via the code below. This all works fine when run in the browser but fails in the **desktop app**.

Opens auth popup:

```
function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
      url: window.location.origin + '/Auth/Start',
      width: 600,
      height: 535,
      successCallback: (result) => {
        resolve(result);
      },
      failureCallback: (reason) => {
        $('#loginBtn').show();
        console.log('Auth/Start failed for ' + reason);
        reject(reason);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

Code in AuthStart:

```
            microsoftTeams.initialize();
            // Get the tab context, and use the information to navigate to Azure AD login page
            microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
                // Generate random state string and store it, so we can verify it in the callback
                const state = '@ViewBag.State';
                localStorage.setItem("simple.state", state);
                localStorage.removeItem("simple.error");
                // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit
                // for documentation on these query parameters
                let queryParams = {
                    client_id: clientId,
                    response_type: "id_token token",
                    response_mode: "fragment",
                    scope: '@ViewBag.GraphApiScopes',
                    redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/Auth/End",
                    nonce: '@ViewBag.Nonce',
                    state: state,
                    // login_hint pre-fills the username/email address field of the sign in page for the user,
                    // if you know their username ahead of time.
                    login_hint: context.upn
                };
                // Go to the AzureAD authorization endpoint
                let authorizeEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + context.tid + "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" + toQueryString(queryParams);
                window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
            });
```

Error in debugger:
VM216:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://mgr360dev.azurewebsites.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at eval (eval at d (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.9.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js:1:38246), :1:36)
at Object.d [as initialize] (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.9.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js:1:38246)
at https://mgr360dev.azurewebsites.net/Auth/Start:15:28

Comment: Turns out the cross origin error is not the problem. Basically any microsoftTeams call I make does not work. I removed all the calls in the Auth/Start to microsoftTeams, successfully authenticate and then return in the AuthEnd. Just calling microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess will return a CancelledByUser error. It is only in the desktop app that this fails. In Chrome and Edge it works fine. If I click the full window popup arrow then it also works from the desktop. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Brad -  Could you please try with the latest package: https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.10.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js

Let us know if you still face any issue.

Comment: So I tried that and still didn't work. However, the issue seems to resolve itself randomly. Maybe when I reboot my PC it clears something but that typically fixes this issue. Note that it usually happens when I switch the logged in user. Right now it seems to be working with no code changes.